# Difference between "errdisable recovery interval 300" and "switchport port-security aging time 2"

Tags: port-security

Just wished to know the difference between -

**"errdisable recovery interval 300" 
and "switchport port-security aging time 2"**

In what scenarios are they used? I have seen that "switchport port-security aging time 2" does not work when "errdisable recovery interval 300" is configured.

The interface only goes up after 300 sec and not after 2 mins.
Any brief explanation is appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The command `errdisable recovery interval 300` helps to re-enable a err-disabled port automatically.

   Generally, it means that a port ,which is currently in error-disable state for a specific reason (including port-security violation), will be *automatically* re-enabled after 300 seconds. You can choose which kind of reason/cause that will re-activate the port back with `errdisable recovery cause` command (you can check further information on this [Cisco page](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/lan-switching/spanning-tree-protocol/69980-errdisable-recovery.html)).
2. The command `switchport port-security aging time 2` can be used when configuring port-security feature on a switch port.

   If you do not choose aging type (absolute or inactivity), the *default method of absolute* is taken into account, meaning after 2 minutes the dynamically learned MAC address ages out. You can connect another host to a switch port.

   On the other hand, if you choose the aging type as inactivity `switchport port-security aging type inactivity`, the dynamically learned MAC address ages out ONLY after 2 minutes of MAC address inactivity (no frame/packet sent from the host with this MAC address).

   This kind of command tells you when (after X minutes) you can connect a host to a port, once the old MAC address ages out (absolute or inactivity).

Answer (score 3):

switchport port-security aging time 2 - The MAC address will be removed from the table after 2 minutes of inactivity.

errdisable recovery interval 300 - The port will recover from a errdisable state after 300 seconds.

Aging and errdisable are two different things.